# How to obtain a JavaScript array of object from an url pointing to a json?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, url

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I have a question: if I have an URL like this: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/ (it points to an array of objects in JSON notation)
what method should I use to create an array of objects that contains all the objects located in this url?
Thanks!

Comment: If your response object is `res`, you can just say 

`let arr = res.json()` and it should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your data using `fetch` then parse it using `.json()`

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
  .then( res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with Angular 6, you should use the [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http) ([Full Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xnpmlpnerkl)). I can provide you a shorter snippet if you need. With Angular you should start learning [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) in order to leverage it's full power.